# Python timezone delta gives different dates when subtracted from date and datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I wrote a python function that gives me datetime or date in the past, with reference to current date.

```
def get_past_date(no_of_days, date_only=False):
    """Returns timezone aware Datetime object in past based on no_of_days provided"""
    if date_only:
        return timezone.datetime.today().date() - timezone.timedelta(no_of_days)
    past = timezone.datetime.today() - timezone.timedelta(no_of_days)
    return timezone.make_aware(past, timezone=pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE))
```

The problem is:

```
timezone.datetime.today().date() - timezone.timedelta(no_of_days)
```

and

```
timezone.datetime.today() - timezone.timedelta(no_of_days)
```

return different date for same input (no_of_days)

`timezone.datetime.today()` returns a date that is 1 day earlier than `timezone.datetime.today().date()`

```
timezone.datetime.today() - timezone.timedelta(6 * 365 / 12)
= datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 21, 12, 43, 741750)

timezone.datetime.today().date() - timezone.timedelta(6 * 365 / 12)
= datetime.date(2018, 1, 2)
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're subtracting an non-integral number of days (6 * 365 / 12 = 182.5). But the smallest unit of a `date` is a single day, and as described in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects), `timedelta` units smaller than the day are ignored when operating on `dates`.

So the `date` operation is equivalent to subtracting 182 days, while the `datetime` operation is subtracting 182.5 days.

An analogy would be:

```
184.0 - 182.5 = 1.5
int(184.0) - int(182.5) = 2
```

Comment: That makes sense! I did not take that into account. Thank you @Kevin